# Javascript window.open docx file / how to close window?

Tags: javascript, html, docx

I try to open a doc/docx file in Word from html link, but I would like to avoid opening a new browser window.

1st try :

```
mywin=window.open("filename.docx","viewer");
```

**Works fine, but opens a new "viewer" window.**

2nd try :

```
mywin=window.open("filename.docx","_self");
```

**Does nothing (tested in Safari Mac)**

3nd try :

```
mywin=window.open("filename.docx","viewer"); 
mywin.close();
```

**Generates an error (closes the window before it is fully loaded)**

4th try :

```
        mywin=window.open("filename.docx","viewer"); 
        mywin.onload = function () {
            alert("All done!");
        }
```

**My alert is never shown**

Expected result :

- Word launched (this works)
- File opened in Word (this works with target=viewer or _blank)
- No child browser window

Any idea for me ?

Test link (echo never shows up) :

https://jsfiddle.net/1ddqhu2d/

Thanks a lot !

Phil

Comment: `window.location.href = 'filename.docx';` perhaps..

Answer (score 1):

What result should be here. Because you cannot open it from browser, just like that for that you need to have command and saved file on local coputer. When you're talking about start saving file then 3nd could be solution and you can close new window after page gets loaded  `window.document.onload = function(){ window.close() };`

Or just:

```
window.location = 'document.docx';
```

To open file in word directly from browser:

```
function openWord(spath) {
        var pause = 0;
        var wdDialogFileOpen = 80;
        var wdApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
        wdApp.Visible = 'True';
        var wdDoc = wdApp.Documents;
        wdDoc.Open(spath);
}
```

To example what i've gave you you should do it like:

```
var mywindow = window.open('path.docx','viewer');
mywindow.addEventListener('load',function(){alert('hello');},false);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried that but I got the following error : Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted and Word is not launched.

Comment: I've update your question of next code what can you use for opeing word. But exactly window location will just download file if the file is not text/plain, text/html or some supported file by some plugin of browser. Then file will automaticaly start downloading.

Comment: It is not possible cause the new window that is being opened can be a different domain. So it is just not possible to track if the new window is loaded or not from your page.

Comment: If you have access to the new window that is being opened -- you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage